# AS3/XML/FLASH : filter by two and more values (Is this correct?)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, filter

I'd like to know if it's possible to filter using two values or more. In this example:

```
var destinations:XML = <destinations>
    <destination location="japan">
    <exchangeRate>400</exchangeRate>
    <placesOfInterest>Samurai History</placesOfInterest>
</destination>
<destination location="japan">
        <exchangeRate>60</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Samurai History</placesOfInterest>
</destination>
    <destination location="australia">
        <exchangeRate>140</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Surf and BBQ</placesOfInterest>
</destination>
<destination location="peru">
        <exchangeRate>300</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Food</placesOfInterest>
</destination>
<destination location="france">
        <exchangeRate>300</exchangeRate>
        <placesOfInterest>Food</placesOfInterest>
    </destination>
</destinations>;

//FILTER -------------------
var filtered:XMLList = destinations.destination.(placesOfInterest != "Food", exchangeRate != 300);
trace(filtered);
```

It doesn't work if there are more nodes with the same values. It shows first all the nodes without "Food" and after that all the nodes  without "300". So, it shows some "Food" results.

Is there an easy way for filtering two or 3 values, say Name, Surname? Or name, surname and company.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var filtered:XMLList = destinations.destination.(placesOfInterest != "Food" && exchangeRate != "300");
trace(filtered);
```

In theory you can put any expression in between the parentheses, like when using an `if` statement. Here's the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e60).

Also note that when comparing data with XML you should use a `String`.

Another less elegant solution could be to use a 2 step process.

```
var filtered:XMLList = destinations.destination.(placesOfInterest != "Food");
filtered = filtered.(exchangeRate != "300");
trace(filtered);
```

Comment: It doens't works. If I add another destination with "Food" and "200", it appears in the result. No matter the "Food" value.

Comment: It will work only if you have one destination with "300" as value. If not, the first filter will ignore "Food" and the second will ignore any destination with "300" as value, no matter the placesOfInterest value. The idea is to avoid destinations with both values, "Food" and "300" at the same time. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Then the only solution is to do it by hand in a for each loop.

Comment: Sorry Pier, I didn't see your post. Anyway, you are right. I did call a loop to do the job. Many thanks for your help.